# How to get data from string buffer How do I get Values One By One In Each String That I Defined Below From StringBuffer

Tags: java, android

I don't know what to do but I am having problem in getting values one by one from StringBuffer from the code that I did any suggestions are most welcome and thanks in advance :)

```
    String n="";
                String f="";
                String ma="";
                String s1="";
                String s2="";
                String mc="";
                String fc="";
                String bc="";
                String pc="";
                String oc="";
                String ad="";
                String s="";
                String d="";
                String e="";
                Cursor m= a.getData(userName);
                StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
                if(m!=null&&m.getCount()>0)
                {while (m.moveToNext())
                {

    //Here I am passing the stringbuffer values to ultimate string field//


         n= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Name"))));             

    f= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Fathername"))));
                    ma=String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Mothername"))));

    s1= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Selfcontact1"))));

     s2= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Selfcontact2"))));

      mc= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Mothercontact"))));

       fc= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Fathercontact"))));

     bc= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Brothercontact"))));

     pc= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Policecontact"))));

     oc= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Othercontact"))));

     ad= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Address"))));

     s= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Sex"))));

      d= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Dob"))));

      e= String.valueOf(sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Email"))));
                 }


//HEre I am getting the values //


           nametext.setText(n.toString());
        fnametext.setText(f.toString());
                    mnametext.setText(ma.toString());
           scontact1text.setText(s1.toString());
                    scontact2text.setText(s2.toString());
                    mcontacttext.setText(mc.toString());
                    fcontacttext.setText(fc.toString());
                    bcontacttext.setText(bc.toString());
                    pcontacttext.setText(pc.toString());
                    ocontacttext.setText(oc.toString());
                    addtext.setText(ad.toString());
                    sextext.setText(s.toString());
                    dobtext.setText(d.toString());
                    emailtext.setText(e.toString());
                }
```

Comment: StringBuffer does not work like that, it appends all the strings provided in a new String. You need to use a collection of Strings, most likely a Map, so you can keep the proper key with each String.

Comment: can you give one example

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

As commented, StringBuffer is for contatenating strings and creating a new one in an efficient manner.

Use some of the String collections insted. Example with a map:

```
// Create the map first
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

// When getting the values
map.put("Selfcontact2",m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Selfcontact2")));

// When recovering the values
fcontacttext.setText(map.get("Selfcontact2"));
```